# Excel SUMPRODUCT Substring Match

Tags: excel, match, formula

I am using SUMPRODUCT to match a cell equaling one of many things.
Using the below formula, I am attempting to match the value `2147` (A single value from a column of many values)  to the below variations of the number `2147`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT( -- ("2147"=Table6[data])) > 0

 Table6[data]   Return Value
1 2147          TRUE
2 2147, 500     FALSE
3 2146-2148     FALSE
4 21475         FALSE
```

The first TRUE and last FALSE values are as expected (success), but I need the middle two to match TRUE (Identify the `2147` next to the `, 500` and between the range `2146-2148`.

Comment: For example 2, are you trying to match to any element in a comma-delimited list of arbitrary length? E.g. do you want "16, 79, 2147, 3348" to be a match for 2147?

Comment: Not the answer, but would you consider having two columns for this data? Also a solution to this given example might not work with other lines, unless they do represent all cases fairly.

Comment: @xidgel Yes! That would be a correct match.

Comment: @MrDogme The value 2147 is obtained from a table column, that contains many number variations (including ranges).

Comment: Do your examples cover all possibilities, i.e. a single value, multiples values separated by commas, and a range indicated by a hyphen?

Comment: @SJR that is correct. Although the search value 2147 may also be represented in ranges as well. i.e. 2100-2200 should also be a successful match (I understand this complicates the problem here)

Comment: Are you discounting a VBA solution? Formulaes could get messy, esp. without helper columns. That said, clever people here could do it for you.

Comment: @SJR Any solution that covers all use cases would be suitable, I am not as familiar with VBA as with other languages however:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses a custom function. If you use it, I suggest you give it a more meaningful name.

So you'd put this formula in B1 and copy down

```
=Match2(2147,A1)
```

In outline, the function checks if a hyphen exists (using Split) and if so, checks the desired value against the lower and upper limits.

If not, using Split again, we split by commas, and if any element of the resultant array equals our desired value we return TRUE.

```
Function Match2(d As Double, r As Range) As Boolean

Dim v As Variant, i As Long

v = Split(r, "-")
If UBound(v) = 1 Then
    If Val(v(0)) <= d And Val(v(1)) >= d Then
        Match2 = True
    Else
        Match2 = False
    End If
    'we could shorten the five lines above to
    'Match2 = (Val(v(0)) <= d And Val(v(1)) >= d)
Else
    v = Split(r, ",")
    For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
        If Val(v(i)) = d Then
            Match2 = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    Match2 = False
End If

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! This solves all my use cases, thank you kindly!

Answer (score 2):

Just for an an FYI, this is the formula:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(INDEX(XFD:XFD,1):INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)))),(2147 >= --LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(INDEX(XFD:XFD,1):INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)),FIND("-",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(INDEX(XFD:XFD,1):INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)))-1))*(2147<=--MID(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(INDEX(XFD:XFD,1):INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)),FIND("-",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(INDEX(XFD:XFD,1):INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)))+1,99)),--(2147 = --TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(INDEX(XFD:XFD,1):INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)))))>0
```

It is an array formula that needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Wow, I knew you could do it!

Comment: @SJR yes a nice puzzle to be sure, but not what I would deem usable.  Even I would have switched to vba for this one.

Comment: Out of interest do you build those formulas out from the inside or can you just string them together as you go?

Comment: @SJR usually I string them as I go, with this one I started with the mid() to get the strings split on the `,` then just did the logic around that.  It took a lot of iterations as I tried methods that failed.  I use Evaluate Formula to step through to help when the formula errors.  Most of the time my formulas are typed into the answer box directly, without testing. this one I tested.